# Javascript access public methods from inside other public methods (same Object)

Tags: javascript, object, methods

**I have the following JS-Object:**

```
var obj = function(){
   this.var1 = "var1";

   this.getvar1 = function(){
       return this.var1;
   }
   this.call1 = function(){
       this.getvar1();
   }
}
```

- all methods have to be public
- all properties have to be public as well

**Problem:**

If i try to call a public method of the obj-Object from inside another public method of the obj-Object, the "this" keyword refers to the public method itself instead of the Object.

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: It's not an object, it's a function.

Comment: functions are Objects in Javascript...

Comment: Yes, but I meant that it's not a plain object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign `this` to a variable(`self`) and use that:

```
var obj = function(){
   var self = this;
   self.var1 = "var1";

   self.getvar1 = function(){
       return self.var1;
   }
   self.call1 = function(){
       self.getvar1();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to return from `call1`. Add `return` and it will work as expected:

```js
var obj = function() {
   this.var1 = "var1";

   this.getvar1 = function() {
       return this.var1;
   }
   
   this.call1 = function() {
       return this.getvar1();
   }
}

var a = new obj()
console.log( a.call1() )
```

Comment: and what if i have to call multiple functions?

Comment: Can you give an example of "call multiple functions"?

Comment: this.call1 = function(){this.function1(); this.function2();}

Comment: So what's the problem? You can call this.function1() from inside of call1. `this` will be what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant this:

```js
const obj = {
  var1: 'var1'
 ,getvar1() {
    return this.var1
  }
 ,call1() {
    return this.getvar1()
  }
}

console.log(obj.call1())
```